# Filter result Pagination not working in yii2 gridview

Tags: gridview, pagination, yii2, pjax, yii2-basic-app

im using Pjax gridview,After I search the results,when I click pagination ,the results changed to default results page not search result.
and my search function is like

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = UserLogs::find();
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,'pagination'=> ['defaultPageSize' => PAGE_SIZE],
        'sort' => [
            'defaultOrder' => [
                'user_log_id' => SORT_DESC,
            ]
        ],
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->joinWith('user');

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'user_log_id' => $this->user_log_id,
        //'user_id' => $this->user_id,
        'user_logs.user_type_id' => $this->user_type_id,
        'login_time' => $this->login_time,
        'logout_time' => $this->logout_time,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'login_ip', $this->login_ip])
          ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'juser.firstname', $this->user_id]);             

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Edit#1: my grid view file is :

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['clientOptions' => ['method' => 'POST']]);?>
                <?= GridView::widget([
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                    'columns' => [
                        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

                       .....                                         

                        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn','template' => '{view}'],
                    ],
                ]); ?>
                <?php Pjax::end();?>
```

Comment: The problem is that the search reset values?

Comment: No.if I search something then result come correctly.if I click pagination of that search result then its goes to default grid view results

Comment: Maybe js error? See in console log browser

Comment: No Js errors found.Normally my grid results are 13 pages,After filter its 3 pages,If I click page number 2 in that search results ,pagination again 13 pages :(

Comment: Try add this `<?php Pjax::begin(['clientOptions' => ['method' => 'POST', 'timeout' => 7000]]);?>`

Comment: @Vitaly not helps!

Comment: Try remove `pagination` settings from `activeDataProvider`

Comment: @Vitaly Sorry not helps :(

Comment: add `$query->joinWith('user')` before `$this->load($params)`

Comment: @SRana Not works !!

Comment: @Jackhad try this `\yii\widgets\Pjax::begin([ 'id' => 'log-grid', 'timeout' => 10000]); `. Working for me

Comment: Not works @SRana ...Seems I may be wrong somewhere.So copied my controller, model and view code here http://pastebin.com/ytnrMFYD

Comment: @Jackhad Did you find the solution? I have a same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Change your POST to GET, this should make the pagination work along with any of your other filters.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by "self join".

1. In your model file write this code for self join.

   ```
   public function getUserLogs()
   {
       return $this->hasOne(UserLogs::className(), ['user_id' => 'user_id', 'user_log_id' => 'user_log_id']);
   }
   ```
2. In your search function write this code

   ```
   public function search($params)
   {
       $query = UserLogs::find();
       $query->joinWith('user_logs as u_l');
       $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
           'query' => $query,'pagination'=> ['defaultPageSize' => PAGE_SIZE],
           'sort' => [
               'defaultOrder' => [
                   'user_log_id' => SORT_DESC,
               ]
           ],
       ]);

       $this->load($params);

       if (!$this->validate()) {
           return $dataProvider;
       }

       $query->joinWith('user');

       // grid filtering conditions
       $query->andFilterWhere([
           'u_l.user_log_id' => $this->user_log_id,
           'u_l.user_id' => $this->user_id,
           'u_l.user_type_id' => $this->user_type_id,
           'u_l.login_time' => $this->login_time,
           'u_l.logout_time' => $this->logout_time,
       ]);

       $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'u_l.login_ip', $this->login_ip])
             ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user.firstname', $this->user_id]);             

       return $dataProvider;
   }
   ```